Why is the Vulgar Latin syncope of unstressed syllables not visible in the Croatian word "Sotona" (<Latin "Satanas")? Why isn't it *Sotna?
Why didn't the Vulgar Latin syncope of unstressed syllables affect the Croatian word "Sotona", coming from Latin "Satanas", to be something like *Sotna? Clearly it's a very early borrowing, before the change from short 'a' to 'o'.
Vulgar Latin syncope of unstressed syllables is visible in toponyms such as Curicum > *Curcum > *Kъrkъ > *Krk (If Curicum was borrowed into Proto-Slavic without the syncope, it would give *Kъrьkъ > *Krak, or maybe even *Krac due to the third Slavic palatalization) and Colapis > *Colpa > *Kъlpa > Kupa (If Colapis was borrowed into Proto-Slavic without the syncope, it would give Colapis > *Kъlopa > *Klopa).

Latin (even "Vulgar" Latin) didn't just systematically syncopate any unstressed penultimate syllable. The quality of the vowel and the identity of the surrounding consonants could both play a role:

The vowel -a- seems to have undergone syncope regularly only in some languages (e.g. French) and later than other vowels.
Syncope did not occur as early or as regularly between a plosive and a nasal as it did next to /r/ or /l/.

Ian Mackenzie (History of Spanish vowels) says

With the exception of /a/ all intertonic vowels had been lost in Spanish by the end of the Early Middle Ages, although this result was achieved in two distinct phases.
The first phase, which appears to have taken place before the end of the Latin period, was phonologically conditioned, in the sense that syncope occured only when the relevant vowel was adjacent to /ɾ/ or /l/ or, occasionally, /s/. [...] Subsequently, in pre-literary Spanish, there was a generalized loss of the intertonic vowel (although /a/, as noted above, was unaffected).

Curicum meets both criteria, and so it is expected that it would be prone to undergoing syncope from early on.
Colapis has -a-, which would not be expected to syncopate early  on based on what Mackenzie says about Spanish, but it does at least have a liquid consonant. This word reminds me of cŏlăphus, from Greek κόλαφος, where we also see syncope (well attested by Romance descendants).
